# Tensorflow Estimator gives different prediction result on each call of predict

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I trained a classifier for my own dataset using TF Estimators, but after each prediction call I'll get different prediction results. I checked the dataset and the data example order  is alright , same for every prediction call , but the model will give different classification result. I'm so confused , wonder if I'm making something wrong.

This is my code for reading input:

```
    def parse_predict_record(example):
        features = {"user_id": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),"ad_info": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string)}
        data = tf.parse_single_example(example, features)
        uid = data['user_id']
        ad_info = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(data['ad_info'], default_value='0')
        test_info = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(tf.string_split(ad_info, "#"), default_value="0")
        test_info = tf.string_to_number(test_info, out_type=tf.int32)

        feature_dict = {"user_id": uid, "ad_info": test_info}
        print("feature_dict=", feature_dict)
        return feature_dict

    files, cnt = get_files(FLAGS.predict_path)
    predict_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files).map(lambda x: parse_predict_record(x)) \
        .padded_batch(FLAGS.batch_size, padded_shapes={'user_id': [], 'ad_info': [None, None]}) \
        .prefetch(32)
    iterator = predict_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    return iterator.get_next()
```

code for prediction:

```
        print("start predict")
        result = model.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn,
                               hooks=[tf.train.LoggingTensorHook([ 'user_id', 'ad_info', 'predict_id'], every_n_iter=500)])
        prediction_res = []
        for prediction in result:
            # print("predictions=", prediction)
            user_id = prediction['user_id']
            predict_label = prediction['predict_label']
            print("usre_id=", user_id)
            print("predict_label=", predict_label)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer,
this worked for me:

```
        checkpoint_path = model.latest_checkpoint()
        print("checkpoint_path=", checkpoint_path)
        result = model.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn,
                               hooks=[tf.train.LoggingTensorHook([ 'user_id', 'ad_info',
                                                                   'predict_id'], every_n_iter=1000)],
                               checkpoint_path=checkpoint_path)
        prediction_res = []
        for prediction in result:
            # print("predictions=", prediction)
            user_id = prediction['user_id']
            predict_label = prediction['predict_label']
```